# Why are there so many idle database sessions in my postgreSQL DB?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I'm using JPA hibernate to access a postgreSQL DB I have running locally on my PC. It's only function right now is serving simple GET, POST, and PUT requests I have running on my app's backend.

Everything is working fine, however I noticed in pgAdmin 4 that there are 11 total database sessions. 10 of these are idle, running application: "PostgreSQL JDBC Driver".

Why are these present? Do I need to address something to get rid of these sessions?

Comment: Your application is using a connection pool and most probably the default configuration of that pool is 10 connections that are never closed while the application is running. If they are in `idle` state there is nothing to worry about. If they are in `idle in transaction` something is wrong. If you stop your application, those 10 connections should go away

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I made a silly mistake. I wanted to write: You probably are using a connection pool, and it is doing its job. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Came across this article. idle connections are not always good. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/performance-impact-of-idle-postgresql-connections/